# Trouble setting up dual monitors on Windows 7 desktop pc

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I've been using Windows 7 for two months now on my desktop. I bought it along with a nVidia 9500GT video card and have been using it fine. The VGA cable was connected to the video card and all was well.

Today I bought a new monitor to use dual monitors and I'm stuck trying to make them work.

I left the first monitor connected to the video card, and tried connecting the second monitor to the video port on the motherboard itself that comes with the motherboard.

I can't seem to make it display anything, it doesn't even detect the second monitor.

Here's a screenshot of the devices:

[image]

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: Could it be that this motherboard doesn't have a default video card? I mean, it has the same port the video card has, I'm just assuming.

Comment: You have to connect both monitors to the video card when the PCIE card is inserted the integrated graphics are disabled.

Comment: @Kyle: Is there a way to enable both the video card and the motherboard? And is there some risk in doing that?

Comment: @Sergio on most motherboards, no. See this question for more info: http://superuser.com/questions/211106/dual-monitors-on-optiplex-755

Comment: I know for a fact there is a question that goes further into details but I can't find it right now... another one:http://superuser.com/questions/44781/can-i-use-an-onboard-and-pci-vga-simultaneously

Comment: There's this one too: [How can I enable onboard graphics AND dedicated card simultaneously?](http://superuser.com/questions/241157/how-can-i-enable-onboard-graphics-and-dedicated-card-simultaneously)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many motherboard manufacturers include some bit of logic that will disable the on-board video card if there is an addon-card installed.  *Sometimes* you can get lucky & they include an option in the BIOS to re-enable or set the onboard as default which will allow both to run in tandem.

I couldn't help to notice that you have a 9600GT installed... most 9600 cards I've seen have 2 video ports already (one DVI & one 15-pin DSUB).  More than likely, you would be better off using both ports on your 9600 rather than relying on the onboard video-card.